# How to terminate a function within a specified time

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a function which determines if an image is avatar or not. I need to terminate the called function once the execution time exceeds 5 seconds.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from PIL import Image
from urllib.request import urlopen


def avatar_detect(image_url):
    img = Image.open(urlopen(image_url))
    total = 0
    pixels = img.convert('RGBA').load()
    width, height = img.size
    colours = list()
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            r, g, b, _ = pixels[x, y]
            hex_ = '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(r, g, b)
            colours.append(hex_)
            total += 1
        total += 1
    highest = colours.count(max(set(colours), key=colours.count))
    return True if highest / total > 0.5 else False


# https://peopledotcom.files.wordpress.com/2018/10/the-weeknd-1.jpg
# -> should be terminated after 5 seconds

# https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/8427649?s=64&v=4
# -> fast execution less than 5 seconds

url = 'https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/8427649?s=64&v=4'
print(avatar_detect(url))
```

Comment: Why not use `Image.getcolors()`? Why convert to `RGBA` then ignore the `A`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Just stick to the main problem. Thanks.

Comment: I think I just need to put the stop within the total once it reaches million.

Comment: There are 180,164 colours in that image. Your list allows duplicates - it is not a set.

Comment: `Image.getcolors()` tells you the count in 547ms.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yeah, I follow your advice and I got a much faster results. Thank you very much.

Comment: Cool, good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a process and terminate it if it's alive after waiting for 5 seconds. The following code can go into the main function:

```
p = Process(target = avatar_detect, args = ('image_url',))
p.start()    
p.join(5)    
if p.is_alive():
    print('Time-out occurred')
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
```

And don't forget to import `Process`:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to what was asked. Still, I don't think it is the right thing to do here (i.e. OP asked the wrong question). The function should be made faster, rather than be moved into a separate process to become even slower ;)